# end Kernal Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkown block (0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-issues, mount

I have the following error after [attempting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50773/debugging-unattended-installer-ua-netinst-rpi3bv1-2) to boot [ua-netinst](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) from a 64GB Class 10 Verbatim microSDXC formatted to FAT32 on Windows7 with [fat32format](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?guiformat.htm):

```
end Kernal Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkown block (0,0)
```

**What does it mean?**

I have seen other questions with same error referencing block [(179,2)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/panic-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-2),[(179,6)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6) and [(8,1)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41027/unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block8-1).

Does it mean a corrupted SD card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what it means?

Yes, or at least, what it is usually indicative of (but this probably won't get you too far in solving the problem).  Either:

- The kernel does not have access to the drivers necessary to mount the root filesystem partition, or
- The root filesystem the kernel has been told to use does not exist.

The first one is unlikely with pi kernels because those drivers are usually built-in.

On a (normal) distribution that uses a root filesystem on a second partition, it could happen if you have a missing or incorrect `cmdline.txt` in the boot partition.  It should be *all one line* and contain:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

However, *raspbian-ua-netinst* doesn't work this way and `cmdline.txt` will not refer to the location of a root filesystem, because it uses an [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) file -- actually there are two of them to match the two kernels (one for the ARMv6 models and one for the ARMv7/8 models); kernels can be built with the relative path of this file hardcoded into them.

These are the `installer-rpi[N].cpio.gz` files.

If you are installing from windows, you will have downloaded and extracted a `.zip` file.  Make sure everything including those `.cpio.gz` files is correctly copied onto the card.

Comment: Thanks. `cmdline.txt` [contains the following](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/master/build.sh#L311); `consoleblank=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1`

Comment: Also,I don't think there is a second partition. [This](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst#writing-the-installer-to-the-sd-card) indicates that `ua-netinst` uses a single FAT32 partition.

Comment: Solved it - It was the first issue. I had managed to not copy the [installer file](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/blob/master/build.sh#L306), `installer-rpi2.cpio.gz` to the SD card.

Comment: I was just looking inside the image, lol.   So that `.cpio.gz` file is an [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs); if you look inside there (you'd need `gzip` and `cpio`) there's a filesystem using [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) as the userland core.  Good luck!